# getting undefined after ajax get call to fetch from postgres db in django

Tags: django, ajax, postgresql, django-templates

I am trying to fetch data from postgres table by clicking a button in the django template page and the fetched data from db should be populated into another div. 
For the same, I am using Ajax get call to fetch the data from DB, but I am facing problem that the value is shown as undefined.

With the Ajax call if I populate the target div with the below, it is working.
$('#childContainer').html(10 + Math.floor(Math.random()*91));
But when I try to fetch the data from table, I am getting undefined.

Here is the code which I have written:-

views.py:-

```
def index(request):
    distinctenvapp = Env_app.objects.values('environment_name').distinct()
    return render(request, 'envconfigmgmt/index.html', {'distinctenvapp' : distinctenvapp});

def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.is_ajax():
        return self.ajax(request)

def ajax(self, request):
    response_dict= {
        'success': True,
    }
    action = request.GET.get('action','')

    if action == 'get_appnames':
        env_id = request.GET.get('id','')

    if hasattr(self, action):
        response_dict = getattr(self, action)(request)
        envappname = Env_app.objects.get(environment_name='env_id')
        response_dict = {
            'application_name':envappname.application_name
        }

    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dict),
                        mimetype='application/json')
```

index.html:-

```
<div><center><table id="t1"><tr>
{% for obj in distinctenvapp %}
<td>
        <button id="{{ obj.environment_name }}">
            {{ obj.environment_name }}
        </button>
 </td>
{% endfor %} 
</tr></table></center></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $env_id = $(this).attr('id')
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { action: "get_appnames", id: $env_id },
            success: function(data){
                $("#childContainer").html("<strong>"+data.application_name+"</strong>");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    //$('#childContainer').html(10 + Math.floor(Math.random()*91));
  });
});
</script>

<div id="childContainer"></div>
```

I expect the data to be fetched in the target child div.
It should show application names like App1, App2 etc, but it is showing undefined.

Comment: which version of django you use?

Comment: Thank you for looking into my issue, the version is 2.2, I will update and let you the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF your ajax request returning JSON content then you have to define datatype in Ajax parameter

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            data: { action: "get_appnames", id: $env_id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $("#childContainer").html("<strong>"+data.application_name+"</strong>");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

For more refere this  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I am glad that the solution is working, appreciate if you give up vote.

Answer (score 0):

I think your ajax request doesnt have url so ajax called current page again

current page is a string and doesnt have application_name

be aware that the `mimetype` argument was removed in Django 1.7. Use `content_type` instead.